# Prove that a functional series satisfies a particular functional equation

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, power-series

I have some difficulties with this problem. Let
$$g(x)= \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=-k}^k \frac{1}{x+n}$$
Prove that
$$g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+g\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)=2g(x)$$
I've already proved that for every real and non-integer x this series is uniformly convergent. There's a hint to define a partial sum $$g_k(x)=\sum_{n=-k}^k \frac{1}{x+n}$$
And using that it's easy to show that $$g_k\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+g_k\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)=2g_{2k}(x)+\frac{2}{x+2k+1}$$
But I have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: Can you not conclude that the $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ yields the relation you want?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I can do that, since I don't know if limits of g(x/2) and g((x+1)/2) are both equal to the limit of g(x). Or at least i'm not sure if I can conclude that, I don't feel so confident about my skill with power series

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the limits exist, so $x$ not an integer, we can write
$$
2g(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = -k}^k \frac{2}{x + n} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = -k}^k \frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + \frac{n}{2}} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n \geq -k,\, n \text{ even}}^k \left(\frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + \frac{n}{2}} + \frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right)
$$
$$
= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{-k \leq 2m \leq k,\, m \in \mathbb{Z}} \left(\frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + m} + \frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + m}\right) 
$$
$$
= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m = \lceil -k/2 \rceil}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \left(\frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + m} + \frac{1}{\frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + m}\right) 
$$
$$
= g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + g\left(\frac{x + 1}{2}\right)
$$
It looks tedious, but you just have to transform indices suitably. If there's the odd term missing at one end of the interval, it will go to $0$ in the limit, so you can still equate the limits.

Comment: Oh that's brilliant! I had a feeling that there is some elegant proof which doesn't use partial sums. Thank you for your help!